# Scheduled jobs in asp.net mvc 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5 application (back-end sql server). I have some scheduled deployment requests to be executed. When i get a deployment request i am performing some task like opening a command prompt and executing some command. This works fine if i run my code directly but if i put this inside a windows service its not working. I read on stackoverflow site that we cannot run interactive applications from windows service. I want to know if there is any other solution to run scheduled jobs on timer tick.

```
   Process compiler = new Process();
   // some code
    compiler.Start();
```

Comment: Check out this: http://hangfire.io/ - works great in my MVC 5 app. P.S.: You can run interactive apps in a service, but you need to enable this for that specific service.

Comment: Thank u, i will surely checkout. Tell me how do we enable interactive applications in a service

Comment: If you go to the control panel -> Services -> open a service -> Log On -> Allow service to interact with desktop

Comment: You need to expand on NOT WORKING. This is a most unhelpful description.